# For long running important apps what Aws EC2 instance type select?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have been checking all EC2 instances and.. from all types I'm debating between choosing -reserved instance or dedicated instance-

Spot and on demand doesn't meet the requirement I think.

I don't have more information about the type of app to be run.

Comment: If you don't have any more information, I'm not sure how you're expecting anyone to help you. What does 'long running and important' mean? Do you need low latency, high volumes, high uptime, etc. etc.

Comment: it's an exam from a university of australia. I have the same question as you.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are concerned with the availability (or up time) of different EC2 instances. The difference between reserved, dedicated, spot and on-demand has more to do with cost than availability. AFAIK AWS does not guarantee different levels of availability for different EC2 instance types or cost structures.

Dedicated instances are ones that won't run on the same hardware as other instances, but dedicated instances can run on the same hardware as other non-dedicated instances in the same account. Dedicated instances shouldn't have any affect on availability.

The other options, (reserved, spot and on-demand) are just different cost structures. They don't affect performance or availability.

AWS advertises 99.99% uptime. This is from their SLA:

> AWS will use commercially reasonable efforts to make the Included Services each available for each AWS region with a Monthly Uptime Percentage of at least 99.99%, in each case during any monthly billing cycle (the “Service Commitment”). In the event any of the Included Services do not meet the Service Commitment, you will be eligible to receive a Service Credit as described below.

So, any instance will be appropriate for important long running apps, you just need to select the instance type that is large enough and pick the right cost structure. You probably don't need dedicated instances, unless you have determined that steel time is going to impact your app's performance.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think its Instance Types you need to worry about - they are just different sizes of machines that have different ratios of CPU/RAM/IO. High-Availability can only be achieved by designing it into both the application and infrastructure. Reservation Types (spot/on-demand/dedicated) are more about cost optimisation based on how long and much capacity you need.

Spot instances are transient - you can reserve a spot for upto 6 hours then it will be terminated. Probably not a good fit, but it depends on how long is "long running"? You get a significant discount for using spot instances if you can live with the limitations.

On-Demand and Reserved are basically the same service, but on-demand is pay-as-you-go vs reserved instance is a fixed length contract and upfront payments. Reserved instances give you the best value for money over the long term, but on-demand gives you flexibility to change instance size or turn off the instance to save money.

Going shared vs Dedicated is generally a compliance question as it gets a lot more expensive to reserve your own hardware to run just your own instances.